# RequestAnimationFrame minimum delay?

Tags: javascript, animation, requestanimationframe

So, `requestAnimationFrame()` is suggested as best-practice for not causing browsers to hang when using high-intensity animation, but what about low-intensity animation?

I'm animating a clock face, with no second hand, so really the animation doesn't need to update any more than once every 5 seconds or so (since there's no visible change in smaller increments than that). Should I still use `requestAnimationFrame()` to let the browser defer the animation if there's other load happening? Or is good old `setInterval()` still best for slower/small-change animations like clock hands?

I'm currently doing something like:

```
setInterval(function() {
  requestAnimationFrame(clockTick);
}, 5000);
```

Is it overkill to nest the two like this?

Answer (score 0):

One of the features of my site is that your "overview" page automatically updates. However, because I added in `requestAnimationFrame` as well, it will only update if you're viewing the tab itself.

This means a user can browse other sites, then when they come back to mine they instantly get to see the update happen. Several users have praised this feature as being very cool.

The important thing to note is that this is done with `setTiemout`, not `setInterval`. Using `setInterval` and `requestAnimationFrame` will result in a large number of update operations being queued for the next frame of aniation.

However, in a situation like this, it's probably not worth using `requestAnimationFrame` - in fact it may even have a negative impact if someone comes back half an hour later to see your clock showing the same time as before just before it updates to the new time... My phone does that when I turn the screen on and it's annoying XD So really, it's a case-by-case decision.